# Tackling Dynamic Models/Data with Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm about to start working on a Django project where my data is not going to be very structured, and am having some trouble on deciding how to approach storing it. The basic premise of my project is to create a database manager that abstracts away the SQL bits away from the user. Basically a user will create fields, and define their type. Then users will have the option to populate these fields with rows of data.

For example, a user could create two fields: first would be *name* and the user could set it to be a text field, followed by *age*, and have that be an integer field. This would essentially create two columns: *name* and *age*.

Up to this point I can visualize what my schema structure should look like. However, when it comes to having the user enter rows of data that correlates with these columns, I am not sure how to approach storage with this regard. Furthermore, I want users to have the option to add additional columns at any point.

Any ideas on how I should tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm about to start working on a Django project where my data is not going to be very structured...

Django's models, by design, are for structured data. You seem to be asking more about model *consistency* than structure, but consistency is also important to Django models.

> For example, a user could create two fields: first would be name and the user could set it to be a text field, followed by age, and have that be an integer field. This would essentially create two columns: name and age.

If you find yourself considering schema updates in response to user queries, it's definitely time to rethink your approach. Schema in Django should be managed with the migration infrastructure, but more generally, this is unlikely to result in a maintainable project (or schema).

When this kind of behavior is necessary, the older-school approach would be [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), which lets you define arbitrary 'columns' without updating schema. But you end up with large and inefficient database queries; this just is not what an RDBMS is for.

Fortunately, [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) are a good option for keeping structured but less-consistent data.

If you want to use Django's authentication backend but still want to track arbitrary fields for users, I'd suggest using [Redis](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) (configured with at least one of its [persistence options](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)) as a secondary store with entries keyed to a user's primary key value, the way you might [use a profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for consistently-structured data.